# Determine if today is between 2 dates AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date

I am trying to set a flag based on today being between 2 hard set dates.

EX:

```
SET @today = Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy")
SET @startDate = Format("2018-07-18","MMMM d, yyyy")
SET @endDate = Format("2018-08-01","MMMM d, yyyy")
IF  @today >= @startDate AND @today <= @endDate THEN 
     set @Flag = 'true'
ELSE
     set @Flag = 'false'                                           

ENDIF
```

using these dates and today being 7/19/2018, this should return "true" but it doesn't.  The ELSE statement always executes and I end up with false every time.  Any suggestions? This is for a cloud page, by the way, not an email.

Comment: I removed the portion "<= Less than or equal to" and the code works so I'm thinking that the cloud page sees the "<" as an opening carrot for HTML and can't process it.  If that is true, how do I evaluate the less than sign? this code is between two %%[ ]%% brackets.

Comment: it does opens up different potential issues to use it, but you can use the actual script tag as well `<script runat="server" language="Ampscript"> </script>`.  This will prevent your above issue.

Comment: @gortonington -- you are a genius.  Thank you! This works! - how do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: I will put it into an actual answer for you - then you just need to select the checkmark next to it on the left side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help others find the solution, here is what worked for @JulieHurtz:

It does opens up different potential issues to use it, but you can use the actual script tag as well `<script runat="server" language="Ampscript"> </script>`. This will prevent your above issue